# 'dict' object has no attribute 'filter' in django

Tags: django, django-views

I have created a class based view

```
class MyLibrary(generic.DetailView):

    context_object_name = 'data'

    def get_template_names(self):
        request = self.request
        template_name = 'my_library.html'
        return [template_name]

    def get_queryset(self):
        request = self.request
        user = request.user
        context = {}
        mainData = []
        userIssuedBooks = BooksIssued.objects.filter(user=user)
        print(userIssuedBooks)
        if user.is_authenticated():
            context['issuedBooks'] = userIssuedBooks
        return context
```

I am getting following error when the view is getting called

```
Internal Server Error: /mylibrary/1/admin
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 149, 
in get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 147,     in get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 2
3, in _wrapped_view
return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 68,     in view
return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 88, in
dispatch
return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\detail.py", line   117,
in get
self.object = self.get_object()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\detail.py", line 38,
in get_object
queryset = queryset.filter(pk=pk)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'filter'
```

I have no clue why this error is getting generated. Can someone help to find what is wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In django DetailView, `get_queryset` expects user to return a queryset(as the name implies) but you returned a dict `context`. You need to do your current stuff in `get_context_data` instead.

[Django doc about adding extra context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context).